# One email to one receiver from Marketing Cloud Rest API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, triggered-send

I'm using Marketing Cloud Rest API and I have already created emails. How can I send one email to just one receiver via the API? Is it possible? I read the [documentation about messageDefinitionSends](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm) and can't find a method for this action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation article you posted is the correct one for the desired task. You need to create a triggered send definition before you can use this call however. This can be done using Email Studio for example.

**1. Creating a triggered email in Email Studio roughly works like this:**

1. Go to Email Studio -> Interactions -> Messages -> Email -> Triggered Sends -> Create
2. Create Triggered Send
3. Complete Properties-form (here you select your external key you need for the request)
4. Select the created email to send
5. Complete Subscribers management-form
6. Set send options
7. Save

Additional and detailed information on the various options can be found in the [Create a Triggered Email Message Interaction documentation article](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/how_to_create_a_triggered_email_message_interaction/).

**2. Send a POST-request to the API**

Use `[restendpoint]/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:[external key of your triggered send]/send` using your instance's endpoint and the external key of your triggered send definition defined earlier.

**The body of your request could look like this:**

```
{
    "From": {
        "Address": "from@example.com",
        "Name": "Your Company"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "to@subscriber.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "SUBSCRIBERS_KEY"
    },
    "OPTIONS": {
      "RequestType": "SYNC"
    }
}
```